# AttributeError using scapy.ip()

Tags: python, scapy

Code:

```
from scapy.all import *

a = IP(source_IP=source_ip, destination=target_ip)
```

I get the error: `AttributeError: source_IP`

Does source_IP need to be a certain class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where did you find those parameters?  The parameters to IP are `dst` and `src`.